# Bug with refresh in python curses

Tags: python, terminal, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I'm writing a program in `curses` and sometimes happens that if I leave the program opened and I use other terminal tabs for a while, when I go using the program again it seems like it has refreshed something and something has disappeared... I cannot show pics or screenshots because I haven't understood yet well when and how it happens... Is there a way to prevent or fix this?

Comment: There's not enough information to guess what you are seeing.

Comment: I know in fact I didn't know if pubblishthis question... but I reallly don't know why it happens...

Comment: For example I use a window with many boxes... When this happens all the boxes disappear like something has been refreshed over...It's like the window refreshes over the boxes..

Comment: getch/wgetch refreshes the window which it refers to (stdscr in the case of getch).  You are likely seeing that.

Comment: I have a similar window like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828804/how-to-make-a-scrolling-menu-in-python-curses
... but with more boxes...
Sometimes, when I switch terminal tabs and then I reopen the tab where the script was running, the box disappears... I can make it refresh by pressing a key because it refreshes every keypress but i have also more boxes wich do not refresh every keypress so I can't make them refresh...
I hope you could understand something..

Answer (score 0):

`screen.getch` reads from `stdscr`, and if it refreshes (due to any change on the screen), will overwrite `boxes`.  You could change that to `box.getch`, as I did in [scroll page by page or line by line using python curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795161/scroll-page-by-page-or-line-by-line-using-python-curses)

The manual page for [`getch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html) says

> If the window is not a pad, and it has been moved or modified since the last call to  **wrefresh**,  **wrefresh**  will  be called before another character is read.

In your sample program you used

```
screen.keypad( 1 )
```

which only applies to reading from the standard screen.  If you read from the `box` window, you should set the *keypad* flag on that:

```
box.keypad( 1 )
```

The manual page for [`keypad`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-keypad) says

> The default value for keypad is FALSE

that is, it is the default for *each* window.

A curses program with multiple windows can choose to read from different windows at different times.  There is only one input buffer for each *screen*, but the side-effect of refreshing the current window makes it simpler to manage updates to the windows.  (For complicated window stacking order, you would use the [`panel`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/panel.3x.html) library rather than rely upon this side-effect).

Comment: I cannot use box.getch() because I have seen that if I use it, it gives me problems: Sometimes in fact it didn't get the right char or something similar..