# Python Curses window.getch() returns wrong value

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, curses, python-curses

Why when I run this code the `box.getch()` returns a wrong value and when I change `box.getch()` into `screen.getch()` it returns the right value? I've been looking on internet and there is no one saying that `getch()` works only with screens. If you press one of the arrows it returns 27 which is the chr of ESC. (This code should print the character untill the user presses ESC...)

```
import curses
screen = curses.initscr()
curses.noecho()
curses.cbreak()
curses.start_color()
screen.keypad( 1 )
curses.init_pair(1,curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_CYAN)
highlightText = curses.color_pair( 1 )
normalText = curses.A_NORMAL
screen.border( 0 )
curses.curs_set( 0 )
box = curses.newwin( 22, 64, 1, 1 )
box.box()
box.addstr( 14, 3, "YOU HAVE PRESSED: ")

screen.refresh()
box.refresh()

x = box.getch()
while x != 27:
    box.erase()
    box.addstr( 14, 3, "YOU HAVE PRESSED: " + str(x) )
    screen.border( 0 )
    box.border( 0 )
    screen.refresh()
    box.refresh()
    x = box.getch()

curses.endwin()
exit()
```

Comment: Could you reduce the example to a bare minimum?

Comment: What you mean? It happens that if I press the curses.KEY_DOWN box.getch() returns 27 which is the ESC value

Comment: Further to @Peter's comment, you may want to read [ask].

Comment: That's a lot of code to look at, most of it's irrelevant.

Comment: Done.. It was not so long... Btw try to launch it.

Comment: my below example code delivers consistent codes and does not mess up the console, no matter what you press.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer (see *[Bug with refresh in python curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30879873/bug-with-refresh-in-python-curses/30880305#30880305)*) is to add `box.keypad(1)`.  There are a few lines which are unnecessary - those are marked in the example:

```
    import curses
    screen = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    curses.start_color()
    screen.keypad( 1 )    # delete this line
    curses.init_pair(1,curses.COLOR_BLACK, curses.COLOR_CYAN)
    highlightText = curses.color_pair( 1 )
    normalText = curses.A_NORMAL
    screen.border( 0 )
    curses.curs_set( 0 )
    box = curses.newwin( 22, 64, 1, 1 )
    box.keypad( 1 )
    box.box()
    box.addstr( 14, 3, "YOU HAVE PRESSED: ")

    screen.refresh()    # delete this line
    box.refresh()

    x = box.getch()
    while x != 27:
        box.erase()
        box.addstr( 14, 3, "YOU HAVE PRESSED: " + str(x) )
        screen.border( 0 )
        box.border( 0 )
        screen.refresh()  # delete this line
        box.refresh()     # delete this line
        x = box.getch()

    curses.endwin()
    exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import          curses
screen        = curses.initscr(      )
screen.border ( 0                    )
e             = curses.noecho(       )
e             = curses.cbreak(       )
e             = curses.start_color(  )
e             = curses.init_pair(  1 , curses.COLOR_GREEN, curses.COLOR_CYAN)
e             = curses.curs_set(   0 )
highlightText = curses.color_pair( 1 )
normalText    = curses.A_NORMAL
box           = curses.newwin(  20, 60, 1, 1 )
box.keypad( 1 )
box.box(      )
box.refresh(  )
e =   x  =  1
try:
  while x != 50 :            #     27  ESC
    box.erase(       )
    cc="WTF?"
    try:     cc=str(chr(x))
    except:  cc="ERR"
    box.addstr( 8, 8, "key 2 to quit, you pressed" + str(x) + "  '" + cc + "'" )
    screen.border( 0 )
    box.border(    0 )
    x = box.getch(   )
except : print("oh my!")
finally: curses.endwin() # avoids messed up console!
```